# How to verify that the memory-to-memory session replicaiton is working?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-was, session-replication

I have a WAS 8.5 cluster, with 2 members, configured to use the MTM session replication.

On the replication domain, Request timeout is 5 secs and Number of replicas is set to Entire Domain.

On both member servers the Memory-to-memory relication mode is Both client and server.

The mod proxy balancer fails over to the next application server (say B) when I shut down the application server (say A) that is serving the requests.
But it seems like the session created on the A, is not available in B.

Is there some way to verify that the session is actually being replicated?

I tried the diagnostic trace logs but couldn't make anything of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below messages to track the session replication

```
WASSession    I MTMStore setDRSMode SESN0188I: Memory To Memory mode for application default_hostibmasyncrsp is BOTH

CWWDR0001I:  Replication instance launched : HttpSessionCache .

CWWDR0002I: Replication instance is active : ADMINIB-NDLUO2TCell01\ADMINIB-NDLUO2TNode01\testses_02
```